# Anychart render multiple charts in one page using Flash

Tags: jquery, ajax, charts, anychart

Hi Guys I was just wondering if any of you has encountered chart not displaying on page when using Ajax calls, I think this is a bit weird because when I used HTML5 engine it works but with flash it just says waiting for data. The reason why I needed the flash component is to support IE browsers. Many thanks for all your input.

Comment: Just saying: You can support IE 6+ without Flash using Highcharts http://www.highcharts.com/documentation/compatibility and other charting solutions

Comment: Appreciate the suggestion but the client prefers to use AnyChart

Answer (score 2):

Have you resolved this issue? If not, please try this possible solution.

here is a tutorial how to to add several charts on the web page:
http://www.anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/index.html?several-charts.html

and here is a sample:
http://anychart.com/products/anychart/docs/users-guide/livesamples/severalcharts/several-charts.html